# How to remove AddThis from my site

Tags: addthis

Someone outside of our organization embed AddThis code into our website as below. I try to remove those code from Cpanel, but couidn't find it anywhere, we are on Magento platform. Please can anyone give me a hand to figure this out pls?

Thanks a heap

Comment: Did you mean to add some code? you write "as below"

Comment: Sorry about the confusing, I mean remove code below from out site. Thanks a heap


<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-56697e9a3b54da26" async="async"></script>
<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->

Answer (score 0):

Seems suspicious that someone outside of organization can change your website. You should probably look into securing your website with better password/security features for admin. You did not really share any code, so I cannot pinpoint any locations for edits.

However, take a look at how someone installs AddThis, and following the steps in reverse (remove the things the tutorials asks to add) should get rid of the module. http://www.addthis.com/academy/en/how-to-install-the-addthis-tools-to-magento/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had look for that section. but I couldn't find any related code under page.xml . Sorry about the confusing, I mean remove code below from out site. Thanks a heap <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools --> <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-56697e9a3b54da26" async="async"></script> <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->